Will grout conceal a joint in a sloped tile installation?
The backsplash appears to sag to the right of the outlet. If you follow the thin horizontal dark tile just under the cabinets there are five tiles on the right and then tapers to 4 to the left to make it visually crooked.  Will grouting help? Our contractor doesn’t want to fix it. Any ideas?



No way to answer this without a picture or two....

It does look like some minor sag/crookedness on the right side, in the new close up picture.  Ripping out that tile will not be easy.  Might reuse the tile(maybe), but think the drywall behind it will be toast.  I would look at it for a couple of days, before deciding on ripping.  Once you put stuff on the counter(toaster/kettle) you will not see it.

Grouting won't change this. The mosaic sheets were apparently not installed on any sort of reference grid, so they weren't kept aligned and straight. Because there's so much variation in color among the tiles and grout, it'll always look about like it does now.
I'd ask for a reinstallation of that section. You'll have to decide whether to implement carrot or stick.
You can always hang a banana hook in front of it. Really, you'll probably forget about it in a few weeks anyway. It only jumps out if you've already noticed it.
